# right to left - increment after chain in return

Tags: c++, optimization, concurrency, thread-safety, circular-buffer

I'm trying to build a single producer/single consumer lock-free thread safe ring buffer.

Here's [piece](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09409d18fce24ff) the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct RingBuffer {
    static constexpr size_t S = 2;
    
    int data[S];
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = 0;

    size_t mask(size_t i) const {
        return i & (S - 1);
    }

    bool full() const {
        return end - start == S;
    }
    size_t size() const {
        return end - start;
    }
    
    void push(int t) {
        size_t i = mask(end);
        data[i] = t;
        end++;
    }
    int shift() {
        return data[mask(start++)];
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    RingBuffer ringBuffer;
    
    // emulate t1 that will write
    if (!ringBuffer.full()) {
        int dataToWrite = 10;
        ringBuffer.push(dataToWrite);
    }
    
    // emulate t2 that will read
    if (ringBuffer.size() > 0) {
        int dataRead = ringBuffer.shift();
        std::cout << dataRead << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Write on the buffer will be performed by a single t1 thread. Read from the buffer will be performed by a single t2 thread.

For what I'm learning, the only concurrency problem here could be in the `shift` method:

```
return data[mask(start++)];
```

because the order of operations must be:

1. do `mask()` with the current  `start` value
2. return `data[]` at the index returned from point 1
3. than, increment `start`

But the code actually will do 1-3-2, not 1-2-3.
The question are:

1. is it possible to to 1-2-3 with this kind of code?
2. using an `-O3` optimization (gcc), can the order of the operations be changed, making the whole undefined? (i.e. on `push()`, move `end++` before `data[i] = t`?)

Comment: No part of `RingBuffer` is thread-safe. A program that calls its methods concurrently from multiple threads is virtually guaranteed to contain data races and therefore exhibit undefined behavior, unless it provides its own synchronization. Simply reading a non-atomic variable in one thread and writing it in another thread is already a data race. A compiler could, for example, simply put `start` and `end` into registers and never consult their memory locations again, since a race-free program can't modify them behind its back.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik that could easily be fixed setting start and end atomic. Done. Now: is it thread-safe? Notice i have only single consumer/single producer, no multi...

Comment: You want to make `shift` symmetrical with `push`, with `start++` at the end. As written, you increment too early, allowing the writer to overwrite the element just as the reader attempts to access it - a data race. Apart from that, looks OK to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how would you fix it so? how can I increment "start++" after the return?

Comment: `int value = data[mask(start)]; start++; return value;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this will do "two copy": 1 to "value", one on "return". I would avoid it...

Comment: `value` is likely to be placed on the register. In any case, the cost of plain `int` operations is negligible compared to atomic operations - if anything, you should be complaining about touching `start` twice.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes :) but that's just an example. I'll wrap the above code as template T, and pass whatever object to it (so, also huge data) :P

Comment: `value` can still be optimized away via RVO.

Comment: Hey @markzzz, I added an actual lock-free implementation to my earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using a thread-safe ring buffer, also requires to access it in a thread-safe manner. In `main()`, the check for `full()` is separate from `push()`, which makes it impossible for even a perfect `ringBuffer` to ensure thread-safety. Because of the one-producer and one-consumer restriction, there is no problem with this approach. However, the consistency of the ring buffer itself is at the mercy of a well-written producer and consumer. For example, if the producer calls `push()` five times in a row without checking `full()` before each, there *will* be overwritten values that are never read, even with a single producer and consumer.

### Attacking the thread-safety problem

The thread-safety problem is twofold. First, the values that are stored in `data` in one thread, are not necessarily visible in another, thanks to the [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) of modern languages and CPUs. This is also true for the *state* of the buffer that is described by `start` and `end`. In addition, access to the *state* is unprotected, leaving room for the compiler and CPU to mess things up even further, leading to [race-conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)!

> Compilers and CPUs are allowed to reorder instructions and locally cache values from memory for performance reasons. That means that your program is not necessarily executed in the same order as your source code and not all "memory" values are loaded or stored directly from and to memory. Enter the need to reason from a multi-threaded perspective and you enter a very interesting area of expertise.

Fortunately, C++ offers language features to amend these problems. IMHO, studying what [atomic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/) has to offer, especially [atomic_thread_fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence), [atomic_flag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_flag/) and [atomic types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/), is worthwhile!

#### Lock-free implementation

Not using a lock requires a trade-off where `push()` and `shift()` "fail a little more often than necessary" to ensure that values are not overwritten or no garbage is read. In general this is complex and very hard to explain. Luckily, the one-producer and one-consumer restrictions together with `start` and `end` only *increasing*, the situation can be fixed more easily.

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t S>
class SingleProducerSingleConsumerLockFreeQueue {
    static_assert(S > 0);

    std::atomic_size_t start = 0;
    std::atomic_size_t end = 0;
    T data[S];

    static size_t mask(size_t i) {
        return i % S; // compiler optimizes for S == 2^N
    }

public:
    size_t size() const noexcept { return end - start; }
    bool empty() const noexcept { return size() == 0; }
    bool full() const noexcept { return size() == S; }

    /**
     * Pushes \c value on the queue, which fails if the queue is full.
     * @param value The value to push.
     * @returns \c true if push was successful, \c false otherwise
     */
    bool push(const T &value) {
        // First load the end offset that we potentially change.
        size_t wr = end.load();
        // Now load the start offset that we will not change
        size_t rd = start.load();
        // Check if the buffer is full. If the other thread calls shift()
        // and increases start, the worst thing that happens is that we
        // return false here while we *could* have written a value, which
        // is better than overwriting an value tat is not yet start.
        if (wr - rd >= S) {
            return false;
        }
        data[mask(wr)] = value;
        // Now we update the end offset, where the fence makes sure
        // that information in the data array becomes visible for
        // the thread that uses shift after end.store().
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        end.store(wr + 1);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Shifts a value off the queue into \c value, which fails if the queue is empty.
     * @param value Contains the shifted value on success.
     * @returns \c true if shift was successful, \c false otherwise
     */
    bool shift(T &value) {
        // First load the offset that we potentially change.
        size_t rd = start.load();
        // Now load the offset that we will not change
        size_t wr = end.load();
        // Check if the buffer is empty. If the other threads calls
        // push() and increases end, the worst thing that happens is
        // that we return false here and that we *could* have written
        // a value, which is better than reading a value not yet written.
        if (wr <= rd) {
            return false;
        }
        // Ensure that information that was written by push() before
        // fetching end.load(), is visible here.
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        value = data[mask(rd)];
        // Update the start offset.
        start.store(rd + 1);
        return true;
    }
};
```

This can be applied in `main()` as follows:

```cpp
while (ringBuffer.push(10));
int readValue;
while (ringBuffer.shift(readValue)) { 
    std::cout << readValue << std::endl;
}
```

#### Using a spin-lock?

Depending on your definition of "lock-free", it could be allowed to use a [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) to guard the ring buffer *state*, using a busy loop to set a flag *if and only if* it was not set yet.

The advantage of using the spinlock is that the number of producer and consumer threads is unimportant: the implementation serves a more general use case. The drawback is [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). While busy waiting is generally considered a bad pattern, the design and context of the consumer and producer can greatly affect *whether that is a problem*. Imagine a completely lock-free ring buffer and a consumer as follows:

```cpp
while(true) {
  int read;
  while (!ringBuffer.shift(read)); // <!-- busy loop!
  do_something_with(read);
}
```

The busy-waiting was moved from the ring buffer itself to the consumer code, that still halts progress until something is available. In this case, using a ring buffer that does use a spin lock is probably okay.

The spinlock is used to ensure that only one thread can change the *state* of the ring buffer, consisting of {`start`, `end`}. It uses an [atomic_flag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_flag/) for that. To ensure that the data written to elements of `data` is visible to other threads, an [atomic_thread_fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) is used. Here's the code, that omits the `full()` and `size()` methods.

```cpp
// be sure to #include <atomic> 
class SingleProducerSingleConsumerSpinLockQueue {
  static constexpr size_t S = 2;

  size_t start = 0;
  size_t end = 0;
  std::atomic_flag flag = false; // flag that is used for a busy/spin lock
  int data[S];

  class SpinlockAndFence {
    std::atomic_flag &flag_;

  public:
    SpinlockAndFence(std::atomic_flag &flag) : flag_(flag) {
      // loop until we can set the flag, so other threads keep looping!
      while (flag_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        ;
      // Ensure that all data that was written in the scope of a
      // SpinlockAndFence in another thread is visible to the scope of this
      // SpinlockAndFence.
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
    ~SpinlockAndFence() {
      // Clear the flag to allow other threads to set it and ensure that all
      // data that was written in the scope of this SpinlockAndFence is visible
      // to the scope of a SpinlockAndFence in another thread.
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
      flag_.clear(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
  };

  static size_t wrap(size_t i) { // static, as it does not use instance values.
    return i % S;  // Compiler optimizes % for & if S is a power of two.
  }

public:
  size_t size() const noexcept { 
    SpinlockAndFence fence(flag);
    return end - start; 
  }
  bool empty() const noexcept { return size() == 0; }
  bool full() const noexcept { return size() == S; }

  /**
   * Pushes \c value on the queue, which fails if the queue is full.
   * @param value The value to push.
   * @returns \c true if push was successful, \c false otherwise
   */
  bool push(int value) {
    SpinlockAndFence fence(flag);
    if (end - start >= S) {
      return false;
    } else {
      data[wrap(end++)] = value;
    }
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * Shifts a value off the queue into \c value, which fails if the queue is empty.
   * @param value Contains the shifted value on success.
   * @returns \c true if shift was successful, \c false otherwise
   */
  bool shift(int &value) {
    SpinlockAndFence fence(flag);
    if (end - start == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      value = data[wrap(start++)];
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

Splitting the check in `full()` and `size()` from the actual `push()` and `shift()` can work. But it still requires a lock in both `full()` and `push()`, as the lock also makes the variables `start` and `end` visible in both threads. Another solution is to expose the SpinlockAndFence, however, that puts *a lot of responsibility* at the call-site.

Comment: about the first statment, that's not entirely correct, and depends by the context I would said: `the check for full() is separate from push(), which makes it impossible for even a perfect ringBuffer to ensure thread-safety`. as said, my case is a single consumer/producer scenaria. if a producer check if that's full, once its checked, it could never be "full" on push, since its the only actor which push. so no other one can "push" in this scenario, except itself :)

Comment: @markzz I agree that it is not entirely correct and should have stated that this is a bad pattern *in general, but allowable in this context*. ;-) 
I do not know if the code becomes clearer if everything after the evaluations of `wr - rd >= S)` and `wr <= rd` moves to separate `full` and `empty` methods. Plus the chance of future mistakes, for instance if the single consumer or single producer requirement is dropped.

Comment: @markzzz, I changed the first paragraphs to reflect your response.